# MySQL migration from 5.5 to 5.7 extremely slow

Tags: mysql

As mentioned in the title, I'm migrating from 5.5 to 5.7, and I have 1 query that totally broke:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) as count, 
detections.vendor 
FROM (
    SELECT id FROM telemetry_user_agents 
    WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 DAY) 
    AND date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)  
) agents 
LEFT JOIN telemetry_detections detections on detections.user_id = agents.id
GROUP BY detections.vendor
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 20
```

On 5.5 the query takes 4 seconds, on 5.7 it takes 400 seconds (!), with exact same indexes and data. I've read about bugs in 5.7, but I'm pretty sure I can find a workaround with some query optimization and/or better indexes.

user_agents has 200k records, detections has 900k records

Here's the structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `telemetry_user_agents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `program` text NOT NULL,
  `country` text NOT NULL,
  `ip` text NOT NULL,
  `operating_system` text NOT NULL,
  `bits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `version` text NOT NULL,
  `license` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `telemetry_user_agents`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `date` (`date`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE `telemetry_user_agents`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


CREATE TABLE `telemetry_detections` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` text NOT NULL,
  `vendor` text NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  `hash` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `telemetry_detections`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);

ALTER TABLE `telemetry_detections`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

And the explains:

5.5

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    95286   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY     detections  ref     user_id     user_id     4   agents.id   19  
2   DERIVED     telemetry_user_agents   ALL     date    NULL    NULL    NULL    202047  Using where
```

5.7

```
id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  telemetry_user_agents   NULL    ALL     date    NULL    NULL    NULL    200866  46.50   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  detections  NULL    ref     user_id     user_id     4   adlice_stats.telemetry_user_agents.id   19  100.00  NULL
```

Any help? :)

EDIT: After I created a bunch of indexes:

5.7:

```
id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra   
1   SIMPLE  telemetry_user_agents   NULL    range   date,date_2     date_2  5   NULL    131741  100.00  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f...
1   SIMPLE  detections  NULL    ref     user_id     user_id     4   adlice_stats.telemetry_user_agents.id   19  100.00  NULL
```

Comment: Are you sure that the index and primary key are right?....it seems that in 5.7 the query is not using the primary keys(full scan)

Comment: I think you need an index on detections.user_id

Comment: @Hackerman, It's taken from a dump, so I'm 100% sure they exactly the same structure and data.

Comment: @CptMisery there's already one, if you look at the structure.

Comment: @Tigzy Can you show the explain output from just the subquery in both cases?

Comment: well I just learned something new. Didn't know ADD KEY created an index. Unfortunately, I have no other suggestions for you at the moment

Comment: @MichaelMior Well, you have it already. Subquery is the line with telemetry_user_agents. I have created some indexes that seemed logical to me, without any luck so far...

Comment: Query caching for 5.7 defaults to off, so set query_cache_type=1 to help with this..  In addition the order by desc now causes an issue called late row lookup, which can force a full table scan.  Edit:  one more thing - which version of 5.7 are you on?

Comment: @TGray I don't think the cache is the problem because data is evolving really fast, I have 1000+ times more inserts than selects. Let's consider the timing are for the 1st query. Also, it's version 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: Is there a way to optimize that query to avoid the full table scanning? Also, 400 seconds is huge! It's not like 3 or 4 seconds, this one takes forever!

Comment: @Tigzy I understand, but subqueries are not necessarily executed the same as when they are issued independently.